# Hide div based on dropdown selection

Tags: jquery, hide, show

I have the following form:

```
<h5>Region</h5>
          <select class="form-control" name="region" id="region" >
                     <option value="">Select a Region</option>
                     <option value="US">US</option>
                     <option value="UK">UK</option>
                     <option value="XS">XS (Sales Team)</option>
                     <option value="XT">XT (Editorial Test)</option>
          </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 portfolio-item">
      <h5>Duration</h5>
          <select class="form-control" name="duration" id="duration" >
                     <option value="">Select a Duration</option>
                     <option value="5">5 Minutes</option>
                     <option value="10">10 Minutes</option>
                     <option value="15">15 Minutes</option>
                     <option value="20">20 Minutes</option>
                     <option value="25">25 Minutes</option>
                     <option value="30">30 Minutes</option>
          </select>
      </div>
```

that when neither options is selected, this link needs to be hidden:

```
<a type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="link" value="JSON feed" target="_blank">Raw JSON</a>
```

I'm using the following jQuery to do so:

```
if($("#region").val() && $("#duration").val() === ''){
    $("#link").hide();
} 
else if{
    $("#region").val() && $("#duration").val() != ''){
    $("#link").show();
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mattography/occnezdc/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listen to the `change` event of both `select` elements. Iterate through them to determine how many have selected values, and conditional show the link based on the count.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/683yv22k/)

```
var $selectElements = $('#region, #duration');

$selectElements.change(function (e) {
    var selectedCount = $selectElements.filter(function() {
        if (this.value) { return this; }
    }).length;
    selectedCount > 1 ? $("#link").show() : $("#link").hide();
});
```

Comment: This works by itself, but for some reason not with the rest of the jQuery on the page: http://jsfiddle.net/mattography/occnezdc/5/

Comment: @Matt That's because the `#link` element needs to be hidden initially.

Comment: Ah, it seems to work now, if I start the div as hidden `$("#link").hide();`, and then apply the logic to the fields.

Comment: It's actually still slightly buggy, in that the button doesn't stay after the form has been submitted. The button only retains the form fields once they've been selected, but not after the form has been submitted. And it requires another selection from the drop downs to enable the previous selection in the URL.